# Flutter Like Button Logical Statements

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

So 'widget.items.likes' holds the value of likes, and I want to add 1 like value if the user pressed the button, and if pressed again it should return to it's original value. Unfortunately, mine keeps incrementing.

```
IconButton(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
    icon: Icon(Icons.favorite),
    color: unpressedLikesButtonColor,
    splashColor: Colors.pink,
    iconSize: 30,
    //add 1 like value if pressed return to original if not
    onPressed: widget.items.likes < widget.items.likes + 1
        ? () {
              setState(() {
                  widget.items.likes = widget.items.likes + 1;
                  unpressedLikesButtonColor = Colors.pink;
              });
          }
        : () {
              setState(() {
                  widget.items.likes = widget.items.likes - 1;
                  unpressedLikesButtonColor = Colors.white;
              });
          },
),
```

Answer (score 0):

declare a variable isLiked to hold boolean value. So that you can increment if not liked;

```
bool liked=false;
IconButton(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                            icon: Icon(Icons.favorite),
                            color: unpressedLikesButtonColor,
                            splashColor: Colors.pink,
                            iconSize: 30,
                            onPressed: (){
                                if(liked){
                                   liked=false;
                                   setState(() {
                                      widget.items.likes = widget.items.likes - 1;
                                      unpressedLikesButtonColor = Colors.white;
                                    });
                              } else {
                                  liked=true;
                                  setState(() {
                                     widget.items.likes = widget.items.likes + 1;
                                     unpressedLikesButtonColor = Colors.pink;
                                  });
                              }
                            }
                          ),
```